# TableLayoutPanel: Adjust size of table and width of columns relatively

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

How to set the tablesize, to scale with the windows forms size ?

How to specify the column widths to be related in percentage ?

like 3 columns with: [0.2, 0.6, 0.2] width-ratio to the window width

Comment: Set the ColumnStyles collection to style.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;

Comment: And how to specify the values ?

Comment: style.Width = number;

Comment: number element [0,1] ?

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columnstyles(v=vs.110).aspx